# C++ iterator/vector not working in release build

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, release

I am using a vector/iterator to execute a method in different classes, this works just fine in debug and in other places where we have used the same approach. However for some reason when i run this code in release i get the following error:

Unhandled exception at 0x011d2928 in FOO.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.

```
std::vector<AbstractClass*> vectorClasses;
vectorClasses.push_back(&SomeClass1());
vectorClasses.push_back(&SomeClass2());
vectorClasses.push_back(&SomeClass3());

CString result;     
std::vector<AbstractClass*>::iterator it

for(it = vectorClasses.begin() ; it != vectorClasses.end() ; it++)
{
   result = (*it)->DoSomething(s1, s2);
   if(!IsBlank(result))
   {
       //Do something
       break;
   }
}
```

Why do this happen? Is the error related to using the vector/iterator?
What got me thinking that it has to do with the  iterator is that when i debug it(release) visual studio completly skip the line where i declare my iterator(this does not happen in debug).

When i debug the release build i get the error when trying to execute the line:

```
result = (*it)->DoSomething(s1, s2);
```

Comment: where is `s2` defined? what is happening in the constructor of `SomeClass1`? show us the code.

Comment: `vectorClasses.push_back(&SomeClass1());` add address of a temporary...

Comment: Missed to include them should just be two different strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot keep a pointer of a temporary object. The memory will be reused, so you have invalid memory access

```
std::vector<AbstractClass*> vectorClasses;
vectorClasses.push_back(&SomeClass1()); // ill formed, SomeClass1() is create on the stack and destroy after push_back call is done, referencing the pointer after that is invalid as it will not be a SomeClass1 anymore.
```

As you need polymorphism, you should do that instead, smart pointer must be prefered over naked pointer.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass>> vectorClasses;
vectorClasses.push_back( std::make_unique<SomeClass1>() );
vectorClasses.push_back( std::make_unique<SomeClass2>() );
vectorClasses.push_back( std::unique_ptr<SomeClass3>( new SomeClass3{} ) ); // if make_unique not available
```

Comment: what are you talking about fox?

Comment: See the edit, it is not created on the heap if you do not use new, so it is a temporary on the stack

Comment: @WeaselFox: if the class has dynamically allocated memory inside that's fine, but we still need space for the pointer or whatever the class holds by value.

Comment: @galop1n If you use `vectorClasses.push_back( std::make_unique<SomeClass1>() );` why not directly store objects: `vectorClasses.emplace_back();` ?

Comment: @TNA emplace_back without arguments will only create a unique_ptr containing a nullptr value. And emplace_back( new T ) is not a good idea as if the vector throw, you will have a leak, so you need the pointer to be in a smart pointer before entering the vector call, so, push_back is the only option.

Comment: @johnzwinck I did this approach since the classes only contained methods, didnt think of the memory for the pointer. You learn something new every day!...

Comment: @galop1n Thats right but why not use `std::vector<AbstractClass>` istead of `std::vector<AbstractClass*>`?

Comment: std::vector<AbstractClass> is not valid, you cannot create abstract class instance, it can be either std::vector<AbstractClass* > or std::vector<AbstractClass&>

Comment: @TNA, because the OP use polymorphism, using a  `vector<AbstractClass>` will slice the object stored in the vector and loss information, not what you want.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't recognize it was a abstract class sorry. In my experience, many cases of storing pointers in containers are  unnecessary but this one is of course valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding addressed of a temporary objects with

```
vectorClasses.push_back(&SomeClass1());
```

the issue is that the object is not valid after the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
vectorClasses.push_back(&SomeClass1());
```

You need this:

```
vectorClasses.push_back(new SomeClass1());
```

In the first (wrong) case, you are storing the address of a temporary object which will soon be destroyed and therefore unusable.  In the second (fixed) case, we are storing a heap-allocated object which will live until you `delete` it (which you ought to do at the end of your program, but if you forget the operating system will clean up the allocated memory).

Answer (score 0):

Following should fix your issue,
it doesn't keep any more reference to deleted temporary:

```
SomeClass1 someClass1;
SomeClass2 someClass2;
SomeClass3 someClass3;

std::vector<AbstractClass*> vectorClasses;
vectorClasses.push_back(&someClass1);
vectorClasses.push_back(&someClass2);
vectorClasses.push_back(&someClass3);
```

assuming you don't delete `vectorClasses` content.